# Free pointer to volatile data

Tags: c, pointers, free, volatile

I'm trying to free a pointer to a volatile buffer (the pointer is not volatile [I think...])

```
void try_this(volatile int* vint)
{
    free(vint);
}
```

gives me:

warning: passing argument 1 of 'free' discards qualifiers from pointer target type

This seems to offer an explanation that would be valid for freeing: `int * volatile vint`
http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2005-January/009652.html

It seems to suggest that because the pointer could be pointing to invalid memory (because it is volatile it could have changed outside the normal flow of the program/thread) and this is why the behavior is discouraged, but... The pointer in this case (as far as I am aware) is not volatile, its the data thats pointed to thats volatile, surely free shouldn't care if this changes?

Can anyone offer a better explanation? (or reason why im totally wrong!)

Comment: Since you must only call `free` on a result of `malloc`, and `malloc` never produces a pointer-to-volatile, you're either doing something wrong or you're OK to cast.

Comment: My guess is that this is from a threaded program, where the malloc'ed area is used by several threads? Just make sure that all the other threads are finished using it before you free it.

Comment: pretty much, embedded application involving ISRs, and it makes a little more sense now that I realise that malloc never produces a pointer-to-volatile, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning isn't specific to `free` and doesn't have anything to do with what `free` does, it's merely because there's no `volatile` qualifier in `free`'s prototype. If you don't want the warning, just use a cast:

```
free((void*)vint);
```

Answer (score 4):

You assumption is incorrect. Since `volatile` is written on the left side of the `*`, it means that you have a *pointer to volatile data*. This data, like any dynamically-allocated data, could change as much as it pleases between `malloc` and `free`. The `free` function does not care.

If you for some reason had `int* volatile vint`, then you would have a *volatile pointer to data* and your concerns would be valid, because then there would perhaps be no guarantees that the pointer itself has remained the same between `malloc` and `free`. But there is no reason to write such code, so it isn't a concern.

The actual reason you are getting the warning is simply because `free` expects a `void*` and you are passing a `volatile int*`. C can do implicit casts between `void*` and `int*`, but if you add a type qualifier such as `volatile` or `const`, then a decent compiler will give a warning instead of silently accept the cast.

You can solve the problem by either typing `free((int*)vint)` or `free((void*)vint)`, they are equally correct.

---

As a rule of thumb: it is fine to turn a regular pointer into one with `const` or `volatile`, but not the other way around:

```
int* a;
const int* b=a;    // fine
int* c=b;          // possible bug and/or bad practice
volatile int* d=a; // fine
int* e=d;          // possible bug and/or bad practice
```